# Testing Python Click Command Exceptions

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-unittest, python-click

I am trying to test the raising of exceptions by a command implemented with the [Click package](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/).

**This is my command:**

```py
@click.option(
    '--bucket_name',
...)
@click.option(
    '--group_id',
...)
@click.option(
    '--artifact_id',
...)
@click.option(
    '--version',
...)
@click.option(
    '--artifact_dir',
    required=False,
    default='downloads/artifacts/',
...)
@click.command()
def download_artifacts(
    bucket_name,
    group_id, artifact_id, version,
    artifact_dir
):
    logger.info(
        f"bucket_name: {bucket_name}, "
        f"group_id: {group_id}, "
        f"artifact_id: {artifact_id}, "
        f"version: {version}, "
        f"artifact_dir: {artifact_dir}, "
        )

    if not artifact_dir.endswith('/'):
        raise ValueError(
            "Enter artifact_dir ending with '/' ! artifact_dir: "
            f"{artifact_dir}")
...
```

**This is my test code with `assertRaises` that doesn't work:**

```py
def test_download_artifacts_invalid_dir(
        self,
    ):
        runner = CliRunner()
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            result = runner.invoke(
                download_artifacts,
                '--bucket_name my_bucket \
                --group_id gi \
                --artifact_id ai \
                --version 1.0.0 \
                --artifact_dir artifact_dir'.split(),
                input='5')
```

The assert fails and it gives `E           AssertionError: ValueError not raised` instead.

**I have found this way of testing, which **passes**, but it doesn't seem very elegant:**

```py
def test_download_artifacts_invalid_dir(
        self,
    ):
        runner = CliRunner()
        result = runner.invoke(
            download_artifacts,
            '--bucket_name my_bucket \
            --group_id gi \
            --artifact_id ai \
            --version 1.0.0 \
            --artifact_dir artifact_dir'.split(),
            input='5')
        print(f"result.exception: {result.exception}")
        assert "Enter artifact_dir ending" in str(result.exception)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Two ways to test for exceptions with click.CliRunner()

The first method is hinted out in the [DOCS](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/testing/):

> #### Basic Testing
>
> The basic functionality for testing Click applications is the [CliRunner](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/api/#click.testing.CliRunner) which can invoke commands as command line scripts. The [CliRunner.invoke()](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/api/#click.testing.CliRunner.invoke) method runs the command line script in isolation and captures the output as both bytes and binary data.
>
> The return value is a [Result] object, which has the captured output data, exit code, and **optional exception attached**.

```py
result = runner.invoke(throw_value_error)
assert isinstance(result.exception, ValueError)
```

The second method is to set the `catch_exceptions=False` parameter on [`CliRunner.invoke()`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/api/#click.testing.CliRunner.invoke)

```py
runner.invoke(..., catch_exceptions=False)
```

#### Test Code

```py
import click.testing
import pytest

@click.command()
def throw_value_error():
    raise ValueError("This is My Message!")

def test_catch_value_error():
    """Read the CliRunner exception report"""
    runner = click.testing.CliRunner()
    result = runner.invoke(throw_value_error)
    assert isinstance(result.exception, ValueError)
    assert 'My Message' in str(result.exception)

def test_throw_value_error():
    """Have the CliRunner not catch my exception"""
    runner = click.testing.CliRunner()
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        runner.invoke(throw_value_error, catch_exceptions=False)
```

#### Test Results

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.7, pytest-6.2.1 -- /usr/bin/python
collecting ... collected 2 item

tests/test_api_authz.py::test_catch_value_error PASSED                   [ 50%]
tests/test_api_authz.py::test_throw_value_error PASSED                   [100%]

============================== 2 passed in 0.05s ===============================
```

Comment: I'm trying to replicate this using built in click exceptions but pytest only sees it as a SystemError<2>. Any ideas?

`raise click.UsageError("End datetime must be after start datetime")`

`assert isinstance(result.exception, click.exceptions.UsageError)`

```
E       AssertionError: assert False
E        +  where False = isinstance(SystemExit(2), <class 'click.exceptions.UsageError'>)
E        +    where SystemExit(2) = <Result SystemExit(2)>.exception
```

Comment: @yuletide All click exceptions get translated to SystemExit unless you use `standalone_mode`. One example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34286165/7311767